# How to write a googletest matcher of a vector of vectors, up to a permutation of vectors and vector elements, using only available matchers?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, googletest, matcher

Suppose one needs to implement a matcher, in the googletest context, for a vector of vectors, e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, up to a permutation of vectors, as well as their elements (so that, for instance,  {{1,2}, {3,4,5}} and {{5,4,3}, {2,1}} would match). It is possible to write a custom MATCHER_P for this. But is it possible to do it in a compact way, using only pre-cooked constructs?

The documentation hints on using a container of matchers, so my idea was: `std::vector<UnorderedElementsAreArrayMatcher>`, but this matcher is internal, so not a good approach.